# Trigger HTML pop up via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make a pop up box appear through a javascript file?

`sample here --> http://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/hPY78/`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ -- http://api.jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `window.location.hash` like this:

```
window.location.hash = "#login_form";
```

Here is the [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hPY78/1/).